# UIImage doesn't load the image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage

Following code Works Fine..

```
scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 1024, 200)];
scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 200);
scrollView1.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.5 green:0.8 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView1];
```

but this one not......

```
scrollView1 = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 1024, 200)];
scrollView1.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 200);
scrollView1.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView1.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scrollView1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"image.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView1];
```

What could be wrong with UIImage? in my complete project UIImage not working anywhere....

In my debugger all uiimage variable shows memory address 0*000000000 even after memory allocation

Note:: ScrollView1 working fine   and   "image.jpg" is the correct argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
```

Try like this. It will be helpful to you.

**Edited:**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"jpg"];
scrollView1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path]];
```

Comment: Yes that was already working...any idea what could be wrong with above code. why variable memory showing null all  the time.

Comment: initWithContentsOfFile method loads the image data into memory and marks it as purgeable. If the data is purged and needs to be reloaded, the image object loads that data again from the specified path. Here image.jpg is not a path. It just a name.

Comment: then according to you what could be the solution of the problem... Complete image path?

Comment: Yes. You can use NSBundle class. I have updated. See this one